# Trying to Install Way Guard Laravel

Tags: ruby, laravel, rubygems, laravel-4, guard

I am trying to install Way/Guard-laravel

and I get a huge error in the terminal. I know absolutely nothing about ruby, and Gems, nor do I want to risk my computer trying to debug this problem.

Here is the error

```
Joels-iMac:work2 joelcox$ art guard:make
Ensuring that you have all required plugins...
Installing guard-phpunit...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
The guard-phpunit gem has been installed.
Do you require CSS preprocessing? [yes|no]no 
What about CoffeeScript support? [yes|no]no
Created Guardfile
Joels-iMac:work2 joelcox$ php artisan guard:watch
05:37:46 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/phpunit' or find class Guard::Phpunit
05:37:46 - ERROR -/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

[#] /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:100:in `plugin_class'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:57:in `initialize_plugin'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard.rb:167:in `add_plugin'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/dsl.rb:176:in `block in guard'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/dsl.rb:174:in `each'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/dsl.rb:174:in `guard'
[#] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/work2/Guardfile:10:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:121:in `instance_eval'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:121:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:37:in `evaluate_guardfile'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/setuper.rb:144:in `evaluate_guardfile'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/setuper.rb:62:in `setup'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/commander.rb:24:in `start'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/cli.rb:96:in `start'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
[#] /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
[#] /usr/bin/guard:23:in `load'
[#] /usr/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'

05:37:46 - ERROR - Invalid Guardfile, original error is:

[#] undefined method `superclass' for nil:NilClass

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:57:in 
`initialize_plugin': undefined method `superclass' for nil:NilClass 
(NoMethodError)
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard.rb:167:in `add_plugin'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/dsl.rb:176:in `block in guard'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/dsl.rb:174:in `each'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/dsl.rb:174:in `guard'
  from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/work2/Guardfile:10:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:121:in `instance_eval'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:121:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:37:in `evaluate_guardfile'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/setuper.rb:144:in `evaluate_guardfile'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/setuper.rb:62:in `setup'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/commander.rb:24:in `start'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/lib/guard/cli.rb:96:in `start'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-2.2.5/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/bin/guard:23:in `load'
  from /usr/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The message

```
"You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory."
```

Tells you that you need to run it as root:

```
sudo art guard:make
```

I have an issue showing how to install it on Ubuntu, it might help you on Mac if have any further problems: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Guard/issues/9.

**EDIT**

You might need to install Ruby and Guard before installing Way/Guard, so,

Take a look at the Guard project : https://github.com/guard/guard

Which will tell you to add proper Readline support to Ruby on Mac OS: https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Add-Readline-support-to-Ruby-on-Mac-OS-X

Comment: Yes I had to reset the permission because before this error, it was giving me another error, saying that it is not safe to install, because my usr/bin was globally set to read-and write. So I called sudo chmod go-w /usr/bin 



then this is the error I get. I checked out the link, but He is dealing with one one the several missing files I need... I am a little confused because this is a brand new iMac,and I have never installed anything regarding Ruby

Comment: You better install Ruby and Guard first, just edit to give you some links that might help you on that.